# Read input buffer in serial communication using python

Tags: python, serial-port, buffer

I am having fast read/write I/O so writing is fast and I can't read all data that are sending from one COM port to another. Let's say I am sending the data 'Hello' from COM2 and receiving 'llo' from COM3, How can read the buffer input and what should i change in

```
    ser = serial.Serial()
    ser.baurate = 9600
    ser.port = 'com'+str(port_number)
    ser.timeout = 2
    ser.open()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ther is a typo:

```
...
ser.baudrate = 9600
...
```

you forgot the `d`

Comment: I have corrected the typing error still i am not achieving the goal. The goal is reading the data from buffer. Let's say COM1 have sent the "Hello" at 10.00PM to COM2, When we open COM1 at 10.02PM it should read all data without any transmission error.

Comment: @OneTouchForHeight, if you want to access data in the past, you need to cache it somehow. It’s not possible to read something later on when it has been already sent.